# error postgresql 9.4 when dumping data

Tags: postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

I have error like at the picture when I dump the data. I change ssl_renegotiation_limit=0 but I have same error. I have error

> pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "tunggakan" Failed: PQgetCopyData failed.
>   pg_dump: The command was : COPY public.tunggakan(blabla,blaaa,blabla) to stdout; "

I use the following syntax:

```
pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "/root/thecontent.backup" "table name"
```

[image: this the picture error]

Comment: please add more description

Comment: oke, I have completed the description